# Get Information from XML file

Tags: java, xml, dom-traversal

I am trying to extract the text value and size value in the row tag from this xml.

```
<items>
    <item>
        <table>
            <row text="foo" size="4"/>
        </table>
   </item>
</items>
```

I was able to get the values for this xml:

```
 <items>
    <item>
         <textbox text="foo">
    </item>
 </items>
```

with this code.

```
NodeList textbox = element.getElementsByTagName("textbox");
line = (Element) textbox.item(0);
String textbox_text = line.getAttribute("text");
```

can someone tell me how should I go about this?

Comment: Will Python work? I recently worked on something like this.

Comment: @ThinkCode Python? I am working on java?

Comment: Use XPath. There are a *lot* of identical questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+Get+Information+from+XML+file

Comment: widget element has no opening tag? can you post the exact xml structure?

Comment: If you succeeded with the second XML example, why won't similar thinking succeed with the first?  It's just different tag and attribute names.

Answer (score 1):

```
NodeList items = element.getElementsByTagName("items");
for(int i=0 i<items.getLength(); i++)
{
    NodeList item = items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("item");
    for(int j=0 j<item.getLength(); j++)
    {
        NodeList table = item.item(j).getElementsByTagName("table");
        for(int k=0 i<table.getLength(); k++)
        {
            NodeList rows = table.item(k).getElementsByTagName("rows");
            for(int h=0 i<table.getLength(); h++)
            {
                rows.item(h).getAtribbute("text");
                rows.item(h).getAtribbute("size");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

something like that

Comment: I didnt consider that widget tag

Comment: sorry that was a typo. i am still trying out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose,

```
NodeList textbox = element.getElementsByTagName("row");
line = (Element) textbox.item(0);
String textbox_text = line.getAttribute("text");
String textbox_size = line.getAttribute("size");
```

If you want to use textbox_size as a number, you might want to cast it as an int.

If this code fails, it could well be due to the seemingly random    tag making this  XML invalid.